# About the usage of the particle に

Tags: meaning

ダメだよ花咲、先生に見つかったら色々ヤバいんだからさ

So from what I understand the に takes the meaning of "by" only when used with a passive form. That is when used with passive form the person/object etc marked by に is the one doing the action directly or indirectly.

And when there's no passive form the action is being directed toward the person/object marked by に.

In this case however there is no passive yet it still takes the meaning "by"

Comment: This one is also related: [What is the difference between 捕まえられた and 捕まった?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36256/5010)

Comment: I think this is a good question to me. So let me answer.

Comment: uhm......how I can answer to **this** question?????

Comment: @gz6p Only what I can say here in this short column is this is the intransive verb of "見つける”. When the verb takes the intransive form, it becomes "passive." See here [link](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1195151636), fontomanie saying, 先生{せんせい｝【に】見つかる：他動詞｛たどうし｝から派生｛はせい｝した被動的自動詞｛ひじゅどうてきじどうし｝, translated, "the derivative form of the verb, 見つける, which is 被受動的自動詞{ひじゅどうてきじどうし｝( Sorry, there is no exact corresponding translation. )

Comment: As well, fontmanie continues to say, it = 被受動的自動詞｛ひじゅどうてきじどうし｝ is kind of a "shortned" form of the verb of the transitive verb "見つける”, to find, when it becomes **that** derivative intransitive, the "subject" would become hard to be expressed. ( Here, who "found" 花咲 is, the teacher. ) Thank you.