# Is this を part of ところを?

Tags: grammar, particle-を

> 彼女は自転車を盗んでいるところ**を**捕まった。
> She was caught about to steal a bike (given, and rather awkward, translation)

I'm wondering how to parse this sentence. Is 自転車を盗んでいるところ really the object of 捕まった. I hope not because I thought 捕まる was intransitive. Or is this the mysterious ところを, and the を has got nothing to do with the following verb?

In the latter case would a more literal translation be "Although (ところを) she was in the middle of stealing a bike, she was caught."
I have little experience with this kind of ところを so sentences like this worry me.

Comment: Related? [Differing explanations of 〜ところを](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54530/43676)

Comment: @aguijonazo I saw that link, but I got more confused. There's a lot of talk about indirect/suffering passive, but I didn't think that could apply here because,  even though the sentence is translated as passive in English 捕まった itself isn't in the passive voice.

Comment: How about this? [ところを 見つかる, this was in a highly reputable dictionary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23404/43676) 見つかる is not passive in form, either.

Comment: @aguijonazo Thanks for the new link; I hadn't seen that one. So, can I conclude that this is indeed the indirect passive, and that's why it uses を? If so, I guess we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: I think so. 捕まる is similar in meaning to the passive form of 捕まえる.